# How to get sharepoint access token

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, java-api

I am using SharePoint account like in screenshot here[image: sharepoint layout]

I am trying to get folder via SharePoint REST API but I am unable to pass access_token because I dont know how to fetch access_token from sharepoint API.

Refer:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Have you even tried to make a GET request?

You don't need to give access token for "GET" requests, for example:

```
    var url = "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Folder Name')/items";

    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
             console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error.responseJSON.error.innererror.message);
        }
    });
```